# What can be done about many duplicates of a fairly specific question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In attempting to answer this question: [Matplotlib skipping dates with empty data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942251/matplotlib-skipping-dates-with-empty-data#comment71071144_41942251), which I think should be noted is fairly narrow in scope, I found that almost the exact same question has been asked at least 7 times before.

- [Intraday candlestick charts using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673988/intraday-candlestick-charts-using-matplotlib) (the earliest I could find)
- [Matplotlib create candlestick chart for weekdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107575/matplotlib-create-candlestick-chart-for-weekdays?rq=1)
- [How to erase spaces between candlesticks and use a dynamic figure size in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275008/how-to-erase-spaces-between-candlesticks-and-use-a-dynamic-figure-size-in-matplo?rq=1)
- [How do I plot only weekdays using Python's matplotlib candlestick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529492/how-do-i-plot-only-weekdays-using-pythons-matplotlib-candlestick)
- [Remove weekends in finance plots with volume overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406973/remove-weekends-in-finance-plots-with-volume-overlay?noredirect=1&lq=1) (the only one marked as a dupe)
- [Remove gaps between plotted Python Matplotlib candlestick data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117651/remove-gaps-between-plotted-python-matplotlib-candlestick-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to remove the gap in candlestick chart created by matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991149/how-to-remove-the-gap-in-candlestick-chart-created-by-matplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I already flagged them all as duplicates of the original (the first one in the list), but seeing as how two of these questions have already been flagged as duplicates (one correctly, the other incorrectly in my opinion), and no action has been taken, I'm sort of afraid my flags will remain in limbo (for lack of the technical term), as this question continues to get asked.

I also just thought that this was such an extreme case (such a high number of duplicates for a question so specific and nontrivial) that it might be worth bringing to the attention of the community to see if some other course of action could/should be taken.